# Chosen user password in registration is not being accepted on Login

Tags: login, user-registration, password

User registrations are working great, except that the password that he chose isn't being accepted when the user tries to sign in, generating a new password from the back-end and trying to login with the generated password works. what am i missing here?

```
$email = $_POST["email"];
$password = $_POST["password1"];
$firstName = $_POST["fname"];
$lastName = $_POST["lname"];
$company = $_POST["company"];
$website = $_POST["website"];
$address = $_POST["address"];
$street = $_POST["street"];
$city = $_POST["city"];
$state = $_POST["state"];
$zip = $_POST["zip"];
$country = $_POST["country"];
$home = $_POST["home"];
$office = $_POST["office"];
$mobile = $_POST["mobile"];


if( null == username_exists( $email ) ) {

  $user_id = wp_create_user( $email, $password, $email );

  wp_update_user(
    array(
      'ID'          =>    $user_id,
      'nickname'    =>    $email_address,
      'first_name'  =>    $firstName,
      'last_name'   =>    $lastName,
      'user_url'    =>    $website
    )
  );

  update_user_meta( $user_id, 'company', $company );
  update_user_meta( $user_id, 'address', $address );
  update_user_meta( $user_id, 'street', $street );
  update_user_meta( $user_id, 'city', $city );
  update_user_meta( $user_id, 'province', $state );
  update_user_meta( $user_id, 'postalcode', $zip);
  update_user_meta( $user_id, 'country', $country );
  update_user_meta( $user_id, 'home', $home );
  update_user_meta( $user_id, 'office', $office );
  update_user_meta( $user_id, 'mobile', $mobile );

  $user = new WP_User( $user_id );

  $user->set_role( 'subscriber' );

} else {
    echo 'user exists';
}
```

replacing `$password` in `wp_create_user()` with `'testpassword'` or adding a new line to the `wp_update_user()` array `'user_pass' => 'testpassword'` both didn't work.

Comment: What happens when you try something simple like wp_create_user( 'testuser', 'email@email.com', 'test' ); does it work or not?

Comment: @AhmedMahdi nop, a user was created with a username : testuser and the email wasn't saved, and trying to login with both email@email.com and test failed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For whoever passes by and has the same problem:

For me, i was using "New User Approve" Plugin that, after deep searching inside the plugin code, generates a new random password and hashes it then overrides whatever password was set when the admin approves that new user. 2 solutions are possible:

1. edit the plugin code
2. find other plugin or add some functions to your `functions.php` that adds Admin Approval to your new users

Answer (score 0):

Dont pass plain text as password, use [this](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_password) function:

```
wp_set_password( $password, $user_id );
```

Keep in mind that it should only be run on user creation (so just once), otherwise the password might keep changing.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.. but it didn't work either, i found the solution and i'll post it as an answer